# Summation up to $n$ terms : $\sum r\cdot (r+1)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question

Summation up to $n$ terms : $$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r\cdot (r+1)^2$$

My attempt :

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r\cdot (r+1)^2=\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^3+2\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^2+\sum_{r=1}^{n} r$$

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} r\cdot (r+1)^2=\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^3+2\sum_{r=1}^{n} r^2+\sum_{r=1}^{n} r$$

But for this method I should know the answers of $\sum r^3$ , $\sum r^2$ and $\sum r$.

Is there another method to find the sum without using $\sum r^3$ , $\sum r^2$ and $\sum r$ ?

Comment: What is bad about finding the sums of the separate sums?

Comment: In any case you know that it is of order 4 (at least assume). So create 4 equations for the values 1,2, 3, 4 and solve for the coefficients of the separate terms.

Comment: @Moti I need to know another method like $r(r+1)^2=f(r)-f(r+1)$

Comment: May be you could use the fact that if you replace r by x, as a function and integrate, r (x) presents a scaled version of the derivative of $(r+1)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(r)=a+br+cr^2+dr^3+er^4$.

Then $$f(r+1)-f(r)$$
$$=a+b(r+1)+c(r^2+2r+1)+d(r^3+3r^2+3r+1)+e(r^4+4r^3+6e^2+4e+1)-(a+br+cr^2+dr^3+er^4)$$
$$=b+2cr+c+3dr^2+3dr+d+4er^3+6er^2+4er+e$$
$$=(b+c+d+e)+(2c+3b+4e)r+(3d+6e)r^2+4er^3$$

We need this to equal $r(r^2+2r+1)=r+2r^2+r^3$.

So $4e=1$ etc...

Comment: Minor error: this should be equal to $(r+1)(r+2)^2$ (i.e. the $(r+1)$th summand). You'd want $f(r)-f(r-1)$ to use the equality you suggested.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you are actually trying to do. Do you want $f(n)=\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)^2$? If so, then $f(n+1)-f(n)=(n+1)(n+2)^2$, not $n(n+1)^2$. This approach will work, but it would probably be easier to write $f(n)-f(n-1)=n(n+1)^2$ instead.

Comment: @Ian; i was using the negative of what Angelo had written - the technique is much the same whatever you use

Comment: But what he started with was not really correct: proceeding this way, the $f$ you've written will be $\sum_{r=1}^{n-1} r(r+1)^2$, summing up to $n-1$ instead of $n$.

Comment: well its his question - i had left the technical details for him to fill in

Comment: You know how to read comments!!! It is clear that a=0. See my comment.

Answer (score 2):

In general: $$\sum_{r=m}^{k}\binom{r}{m}=\binom{k+1}{m+1}$$ wich can be shown by induction.

Application:

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}r\left(r+1\right)^{2}=3!\sum_{r=3}^{n+2}\binom{r}{3}-2!\sum_{r=2}^{n+1}\binom{r}{2}=6\binom{n+3}{4}-2\binom{n+2}{3}$$